# How to hide the "help-block" on an Image field in the Comment Form

Tags: comments

I have added an image field to the comments.

This allows to my visitors to add images with a comment.

But I have annoying "help-block" for the image field in the form of adding a comment.

[image: Drupal help-block for an image field in the Comment Form]

How to gracefully to remove this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7

I done it through the ***node_view_alter*** hook and my custom theme.

In the theme's **template.php** file I added the following function

```
function MyThemeName_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  if ($build['#node']->type !== 'My_Node_Type'){
    return;
  }

  // Your image field can not exist while saving comment.
  if(isset($build['comments']['comment_form']['My_Image_Field'])){
    // We can't use the unset function. Otherwise we can get something like this:
    // Notice: Undefined index: #file_upload_description in theme_file_widget_multiple() (row 863 file .../docs/modules/file/file.field.inc).
    $build['comments']['comment_form']['My_Image_Field']['und']['#file_upload_description'] = NULL;
  }
}
```

This removes the entire ***<p class="help-block">...</p>*** element.